# Kinectjs line.points returns string and not array?

Tags: html, kineticjs

With version 4.7.4 of kineticjs, I was able to use blob.getPoints() to return the x,y values of each point in the blob.

With version 5.0.1 the equivalent - line.points() returns a string of x,y values. 
With 4.74 I could determine the max and min bounds easily, however there doesn't seem to be an easy way to do it with 5.0.1

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`line.points()` returns 1-d array of coordinates:

```
[x1, y1, x2, y2, ..., xn, yn]
```

if you need {x, y} points:

```
var points = line.points();
for (var i = 0; i < points.length / 2; i++) {
    var point = {
        x : points[i * 2],
        y : points[i * 2 + 1]
    };
    console.log(point);
};
```